# slack API - webhook - gitlab-ci.yml - invalid payload with curl

Tags: xml, curl, gitlab-ci, slack

I want to setup that a slack channel receives a xml payload.

Using curl in a gitlab-ci.yml file, this script is going through:

`- "curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: text/xml' -d '@/PATH/TO/FILE/data.xml' ${URL}"`

**OR**

`- curl -F file=@/PATH/TO/FILE/data.xml ${URL}`.

Could someone enlighten me, as the xml file is valid, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to send files via webhook. [The files.upload API method](https://api.slack.com/messaging/files/uploading#uploading_files) is the method of choice for this task.

Plus, invalid_payload typically indicates that received request is malformed —  the JSON is structured incorrectly, or the message text is not properly escaped. In my case, an xml file..

Comment: HTTP Method access: 
POST `https://slack.com/api/files.upload`